# Need solution for if statement logic

Tags: javascript

I need help on a condition logic using if statement as following:

- Variables A and B contain 3 properties which is level1, level2 and level3.
- level1 and level2 can be 0 or more and level3 is null or numeric.
- Variables A and B can be null.

Currently I have this condition:

```
if (A.level1 == 0 and B.level1 == 0) {
  code here
} else if (A.level2 == 0 and B.level2 == 0) {
  code here
} else if (A.level3 != null and B.level3 != null) {
  code here
}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't handle the `Variables A and B can be null` part. The code should handle that part like this:

- When A is null, B will still go through the same condition but without A and vice versa.
- However, if A and B is null then the condition will be false at once.

I have problem in how to implement the `Variables A and B can be null` part in my condition, any advice?

Comment: what is your Question?

Comment: I want to compare 2 arrays which will contain 3 properties of level1, level2 and level3. But array A or B can be undefined but not both undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `A` and `B` isNull check in your condition:

```
if (A == null && B == null) {
    return;
} else if ((A == null || A.level1 == 0) && (B == null || B.level1 == 0)) {
    // code here
} else if ((A == null || A.level2 == 0) && (B == null || B.level2 == 0)) {
    // code here
} else if ((A == null || A.level3 != null) && (B == null || B.level3 != null)) {
    // code here
}
```

**Explanation**,

Take A for example in this `else if ((A == null || A.level1 == 0) && (B == null || B.level1 == 0))` statement:

By putting the `A == null ||` in `(A == null || A.level1 == 0) && (B == null || B.level1 == 0)`, if A is null, then this `A.level1 == 0` check will be ignored, thus the check will be equivalent with `else if (B == null || B.level1 == 0)`.

Since the first `if` already check `A == null && B == null`, the `else if` below won't have A and B both null. Therefore now `else if ((A == null || A.level1 == 0) && (B == null || B.level1 == 0))` will be equivalent to `else if (B.level1 == 0)`.

**p.s. Here we are taking advantage of the `||` characteristic, that is if the first condition is fulfilled, the second condition will be ignored.**

Comment: Thanks a million. This is exactly what I am looking for. And again thanks a million to trillion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
// Both A and B are null
if(A == null && B == null){
    // do something
}
// Only A is null
else if(A == null){
    if(B.level1 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(B.level2 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(B.level3 != null){
        // do something
    }
}
// Only B is null
else if(B == null){
    if(A.level1 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(A.level2 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(A.level3 != null){
        // do something
    }
}
// Neither A or B are null
else{
    if(A.level1 == 0 && B.level1 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(A.level2 == 0 && B.level1 == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if(A.level3 != null && B.level3 != null){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check for falsy values of `A` or `B` first and then check the properties.

```js
var A = null,
    B = null;

if (!A && !B) {
    console.log('A or B is null');
} else if (A.level1 === 0 && B.level1 === 0) {
    console.log(1);
} else if (A.level2 === 0 && B.level2 === 0) {
    console.log(2);
} else if (A.level3 != null && B.level3 != null) {
    console.log(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle A and B separately,

if(!A){

```
if(A.level1 === 0 && A.level2 ===0){

}
else if(A.level1 === 0){


}
else if(A.level1 > 0){

}


if(A.level2 === 0){

}
else if(A.level2 > 0){

}

if(A.level3 === null){

}
else if (typeof (A.level3) === "number"){
}
```

}

same for B here...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, if both A and B conditions is doing the same thing, should i create a function for that?
Eg. When level1 == 0 i will do code level1 either from A or B same as level2 and level3.

Comment: yes! you could create a function take the parameter (either A or B). Good approach!